# props.images.map is not a function (function component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently this two components are child components, so what I want to achieve here is to pass the props from Search component to Images component. Because I wrote everything in a function component, I thought this might be a great place for me

When user enters something in the input field it will automatically search for new images. In order to give you a better understanding of my issue, I will put a link to Codesandbox here. So I want to pass the props to the sibling component, so it will output the filtered search result.

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-dawn-khouk

So only files you need to look at are: Search.js, Images.js

Comment: your images property is not an array

Comment: check if `props.images` is an array. `Array.isArray(props.images) && props.images.map`

Comment: I guess the images are there in nested hierarchy. Please use `props.images.images`

Comment: images: Array(0)}images: []__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `images` prop is actually an array. Can you do some debugging to figure out what your `images` object actually is?

Using propTypes is a way to have react help, and if it is nullable (i.e. not `isRequired`), then use a guard on it:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Image from "./Image";

const propTypes = {
  images: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // used as key
      src: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // used for image source
      <... other object properties ...>
    })
  ),
};

const Images = ({ images }) => {
  const images = images && images.map((image) => {
    return <Image key={image.id} image={image}/>
  });

  return <div className="images">{images}</div>;
}

Images.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Images;
```